# How do I change the characters in the middle of a String in Java?

Tags: string, google-maps

I have a String which serves as a URL for a googleMaps image in my interface, and I have to be able to change the zoom level on it arbitrarily, I've got:

```
String coordinates=latitude+","+longitude;
String url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?    center="+coordinatess+"&zoom=12&size=400x400&markers=color:red|"+coordinatess;
```

where the level of zoom on the image is determined by the number after the "&zoom=" tag, how can I change this number efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java strings are immutable, so you only can change it by overwriting the whole string. However you could save the static parts as

```
String urlFirstPart="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?    center="+coordinatess+"&zoom=";
String urlLastPart="&size=400x400&markers=color:red|"+coordinatess;
```

and then update the url to zoom `zoom` by

```
url = urlFirstPart+zoom+urlLastPart
```